# Jest formats my custom exception type as [object Object] in async tests

Tags: node.js, exception, jestjs

I am trying to create a custom error class to contain information about failed requests for my Jest tests.

```
/**
 * Custom error class for errors that happen when fetching data
 */
class ApiError extends Error {
  error: string;
  code: number | null;

  /**
   * Custom error class for errors that happen when fetching data
   */
  constructor (code: number | null, error: string) {
    super(error);
    this.error = error;
    this.code = code;
  }
}

export default ApiError;
```

However, I have noticed that when this error is thrown in async code in order to reject a promise, Jest formats it as `[object Object]`.

```
  ● /auth/register › allows users to register

    [object Object]

      78 |     // All 400 and 403 errors have an error message
      79 |     const errorMessage = (json as { error: string }).error;
    > 80 |     throw new ApiError(res.status, errorMessage);
         |           ^
      81 |   }
      82 |   if (![200, 304].includes(res.status)) {
      83 |     // Unknown error

      at apiFetch (tests/api/fetch.ts:80:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/auth/register.test.ts:5:27)
```

This means that seeing information about the particular error is very challenging. How can I get Jest to print out my error in a readable format like it does for other error types?

I have tried adding a `toString` method, but according to my debugger it doesn't even get called.

```
toString() {
  return `ApiError: [${this.code}] ${this.error}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that jest displays the exceptions `message` property regardless of the `toString` method. This combined with an unexpected error message type (I forgot to stringify it, so it ended up being an object rather than a string) meant that the error was displayed as `[object Object]`.

I resolved this by passing my desired error message as the `message` property to the super constructor, `JSON.stringify`-ing the given error message if required.

```
class ApiError extends Error {
  error: string;
  code: number | null;

  /**
   * Custom error class for errors that happen when fetching data
   */
  constructor (code: number | null, error: string | object) {
    if (typeof error === 'object') {
      error = JSON.stringify(error);
    }
    super(`ApiError: [${code}] ${error}`);
    this.error = error;
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```